# Gravity and Light and the manipulation of space time

Tags: magic, gravity, light

ANOTHER EDIT: I think the answers so far have made me realize that there's not going to be a way to do what I want creatively and adhere to anything resembling real universe physics.  I appreciate the time everyone has taken to answer.  Back to the drawing board...

Question: what types of spells could a Mage who manipulates light and a Mage who manipulates gravity do together?

Background:
I have built a magic system where Mages have self-limiting access to an apparently limitless power source. *EDIT TO EXPLAIN* The magic source is called aether and is I stress limitless. The mages do not hold power within themselves, they 'conduct it' through their bodies when in contact with a surface which contains aether. Similar concept to electrical current. But it isn't electricity.
The Mage can only wield the power through study and understanding of the "forms" of their craft. For this reason, mages specialize in a particular craft. There are seven major categories of craft but for this question, I would like to discuss two: lihtcraft and toolcraft.

Lihtcraft is the ability to manipulate light (both visible and invisible). The typical lihtcrafter spends his life constructing orbs and heat lamps. My lihtcrafter MC is a detective who uses his craft to detect the "scatter" Mages leave behind when they cast illegal spells.

Toolcraft is the ability to manipulate gravity. Most toolcrafters are not able to do much more impressive than heft objects half their body weight. But my other MC toolcrafter is much more powerful. Important note, my Mages cannot fly. Their magic only works if they are physically connected to Earth.

An important subplot of my story is that my toolcrafter and my lihtcrafer are "mage-falawes"--they have a unique ability to combine forces.

I am trying to think of the wonders, great and small, that these two forces could do together in a logical, albeit, fantastical way. I've thought about how they might affect spacetime. Or the gravitational lens. Or the interaction of gravitons and light.  But I haven't thought of many *applications* of such abilities.
The most interesting thoughts I've had is about the potential of invisibility or "freezing time".  But I wonder if my fellow worldbuilders have more creative ideas.

Also: if you happen to have thoughts about interesting ways lihtcraft and toolcraft might be applied individually, I'd love to hear those as well.  I'm constantly worrying there's some major thing I've gotten that will create a giant plot hole.

Comment: The word *lihtcraft* has an extremely unusual form for an English word -- the sequence i h t does not occur in modern English spelling. (It does occur in Old English, but that's a different language). Either *li**g**htcraft* (English), or *Lichtkraft* German-ish "light-power" (actual German is *Leuchtkraft* "luminosity").

Comment: Your mage has thus destroyed both Special and General Relativity, and can pretty much eliminate or rebuild the Universe however he wishes.

Comment: @AlexP the language of my magic system is based on Anglish I have logical reasons for that...but I doubt that matters atm

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the thought had crossed my mind...

Comment: @AlexP have you ever read uncleftish beholding?  I'm obsessed...

Comment: They could definitely create all sorts of exotic mesons with half-lifes into the double-digit nanosecond range.

Comment: Yes, I read *Uncleftish Beholding*; nevertheless, my comment *is* valid. The modern English spelling is *li**g**ht*, and yes, for real, the letter sequence i h t cannot appear in the spelling of a modern English word, unless it's a very recent borrowing from a foreign language which still retains its original spelling. The point is that nobody will have any idea how to pronounce *lihtcraft*, because they don't have any example in the language.

Comment: @AlexP I'm not using modern English. I already explained that. I can spell it however I want its fiction. But more importantly, my magic system is written in Anglish not English. It seems pretty ludicrious thing to debate, however, your opinion is noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stretching the limits of physics, but well...there's magic involved:
Gravitymagic could make lightmagic have mass (or behalve as it had). Then you could have a slower-than-lightspeed rod of light with mass and momentum, could be quite damaging.

Answer (score 0):

> I've thought about how they might affect spacetime. Or the gravitational lens. Or the interaction of gravitons and light. But I haven't thought of many applications of such abilities.

Right, but...

> Lihtcraft is the ability to manipulate light (both visible and invisible). The typical lihtcrafter spends his life constructing orbs and heat lamps. My lihtcrafter MC is a detective who uses his craft to detect the "scatter" Mages leave behind when they cast illegal spells.
>
> Toolcraft is the ability to manipulate gravity. Most toolcrafters are not able to do much more impressive than heft objects half their body weight. But my other MC toolcrafter is much more powerful. Important note, my Mages cannot fly. Their magic only works if they are physically connected to Earth

There's the problem. Not enough raw power. Light is *fast*, not to the point where it can't be affected by incredibly large amounts of gravity, but fast to the point where it can be noticeably affected only by massive amounts of gravity.

If the upper limit of gravity manipulation is a few dozen kilos of mass, there's no way to meaningful manipulate light with it. Sure, you can do things which flagrantly ignore the law of physics if you felt like it, but the feel I'm getting here is that you're going for a harder sort of magic system which pays attention to the laws of reality, and thus there really isn't anything you can do with that little power.

Comment: I've always felt like the hardest of magics are kind of a bummer...so I'm trying to strike a happy balance. If my raw power is *magic* (in this case a nebulous thing called aether) then why not? My mages do not hold power themselves. They are conduits.  I should probably edit the question.

Comment: Because Stephen's answer, basically. The energy needed to do that would also give your mages the power to crack the Earth in half and fry it on the Sun. (That's a slight exaggeration, but not by much.) I didn't give that as an answer because you gave power levels in the question which just weren't high enough.

Answer (score 0):

When distorting spacetime with gravity, you have to be aware than any manipulations you do that noticeably affect light will affect other stuff an awful lot *more* noticeably.  To take gravitational lensing as an example, a GL deflects light passing by with an offset $b$ by an angle $\hat\alpha$:

$${\hat {\alpha }}={\frac {4GM}{c^{2}b}}$$

Just taking orders-of-magnitude estimates here, for measurable deflection over centimetre range (eg to make a pocket magnifying glass) you need to create a point mass of around $\mathrm{10^{25}\ kg}$.  By the ordinary principle of gravitation:

$$a={\frac {GM}{r^{2}}}$$

That's going to pull in an object a hundred kilometers away with a force of about $\mathrm{10000\ g}$; ie it's going to do catastrophic damage to a sizeable fraction of the planet's surface.